# Embedded Jetty and SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to run an embedded Jetty and would like to expose a soap webservice. The project is loaded as a WAR generated by netbeans. The webservice is generated from a WSDL. What is the simplest way to add SOAP support to embedded Jetty

Answer (score 2):

The [axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/index.html) web services framework can be deployed as a normal web application onto your embedded Jetty instance.

It provides a framework for the execution of your web service. You can embed such services within the Axis2 war file or deploy them separately .aar files (Special Axis2 archive file format)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a bridge to use [JAX-WS with Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/J2se6HttpServerSPI). Though I never use it personally.

Comment: Is it required to use JAX-WS or is there something built into Java 6

Comment: Also the link gives an invalid svn co path

Comment: alt link (other branches are there too:) - https://svn.codehaus.org/jetty-contrib/jetty/branches/jetty-6.1/contrib/j2se6/

Comment: @ewernli what exactly am i supposed to be looking for. I am already using the hightide distribution do I need something else